# EventHub Exception :Cannot allocate more handles to the current session or connection

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I have C# console application through which I am sending data to event hub frequently.This console application basically read some data from SQL storage and start pushing data to event hub.

This entire program run in endless loop/fashion  like in while control whenever it receive any data in SQL it pulls data from there and start sending to Event hub.

But at some moment I got this error.

"Cannot allocate more handles to the current session or connection.The maximum number of handles allowed is 4999.Please free up resources any try again. at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common......

When I restarted this console application its working fine.But I don't know why I got this error .

Please help me.

Thanks & Regards,

RK

Comment: In general pls. add more info (for ex: evenhubs code snippet's used) on your problem - that will allow the answer'er to find the problem in single iteration :)

Answer (score 14):

TLDR: **In the 'send to EventHub logic', make sure that you are reusing (cache'ing) the same sender instance.**

**The Why**:

EventHubs is designed to support very large scale high-thruput low-latency event'ing systems. Hence, we chose to rely on a very performant protocol for all Runtime Operations - namely [Amqp](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf). The goodness of [Amqp Protocol](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf) comes into play when the application built on top of it fully leverages its strengths. This is how EventHubs Object Model maps to Amqp artifacts:

1. `EventHubClient` maps to one single AmqpConnection. Cardinality is 1:1. If exact same ConnectionString is specified while Creating [`EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn879106.aspx) - The underlying physical socket will be shared - but the amqp Artifact - AmqpConnection is still different.
2. Whenever client invokes `EventHubClient.Send(EventData)`, internally, `EventHubClient` creates **1 AmqpSession** and **1 AmqpLink in that Session** on the AmqpConnection created by `EventHubClient`. This Session and Link are re-used as long as the same `EventHubClient` instance is used for subsequent Sends.
3. Whenever any Management operation is performed on the `EventHubClient` - since, mgmt. operations (like getPartitionInfo) are always request-response and require 2-way communication - `EventHubClient` creates **1 AmqpSession** and **2 AmqpLink's in that Session - one Link for the Request & other link for Response (Ex: imagine the result of a REST `Get` call)**.
4. Whenever, any child entities are Created from `EventHubClient` - like `EventHubSender` or `EventHubReceiver` - `EventHubClient` creates **a brand new AmqpSession** && **an AmqpLink in that Session**.

**Key takeaways for the Client Application using eventhub SDK are**:

Every Time an `EventHubClient` instance is created - a real physical socket is created underneath.

Every Time an `EventHubSender` or an `EventHubReceiver` instance is created that socket created by `EventHubClient` is re-used and on top of it:
 (a) an AmqpSession is created - no. of AmqpSessions are limited to 5k per connection - **I guess this is the limit your client application is hitting above**.
 (b) AmqpLink is created inside that Session - which will inturn trigger Entity Resolution in EventHubs Service (which is **a tiny bit expensive** compared to sending on an existing `EventHubSender`).

[More on Event Hubs.](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Issue resolved now I am creating only single instance of Event hub client for sending all messages/events rather than creating Event hub client instance for each messages/events.

Comment: @sreeram Is this session to EventHubClient instance relation documented anywhere? I've tried searching and can not find this in any of the Azure documentation. Even the Event Hubs Programming Guide [1] doesn't make mention of this. It'd be great if you could point me in the right direction.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved now I am creating only single instance of Event hub client for sending all messages/events rather than creating Event hub client instance for each messages/events.