# Azure Event Hubs : QuotaExceededException : 4999 handles limit

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Event Hub library for C# in WebApi App. And I got this exception on message sending:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Cannot allocate more handles to the current session or connection. The maximum number of handles allowed is 4999. Please free up resources and try again., referenceId: d975f39c71a14ae5915c9adca322e110_G15"
"ExceptionType":"Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QuotaExceededException"
```

I thought that instantiantion of `EventHubProducerClient` one time and reusing it instead of creating its instance on each message sending (with `IAsyncDisposable` pattern) will help as mentioned here
[EventHub Exception :Cannot allocate more handles to the current session or connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836828/eventhub-exception-cannot-allocate-more-handles-to-the-current-session-or-conne). But it did not.

I believe there might be some more global issue. Might be missing something.

- I am using single event hub with 7 consumer groups each of which is used by separate web application (single); well actually there is additional consumer group ($Default) but it is not used;
- For receiving messages I use `EventProcessorClient`;
- I use `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` 5.2.0 and `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor` 5.2.0 packages;
- Here is the whole code (did everything according to quickstart):

```
    public class EventHubService : SubscriberBase
    {
        private readonly Action<string> errorHandler;
        private readonly BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient;
        private readonly EventProcessorClient eventProcessorClient;
        private readonly EventHubProducerClient eventHubProducerClient;
        private readonly int eventsToCheckpoint;
        private readonly Timer checkpointTimer;
        private int eventsSinceLastCheckpoint;
        private bool shouldUpdateCheckpoint;

        public EventHubService(EventHubSettings settings, Action<string> errorHandler) : base()
        {
            this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
            eventHubProducerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(settings.ConnectionString, settings.EventHubName);

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settings.GroupId))
            {
                eventManager = new EventManager();

                blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(settings.StorageConnectionString, settings.BlobContainerName);
                eventProcessorClient = new EventProcessorClient(blobContainerClient, settings.GroupId, settings.ConnectionString, settings.EventHubName);

                eventsToCheckpoint = settings.EventsToUpdateCheckpoint;
                checkpointTimer = new Timer(settings.IntervalToUpdateCheckpoint.TotalMilliseconds);
                checkpointTimer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => shouldUpdateCheckpoint = true;
            }
        }

        public override void Start()
        {
            eventProcessorClient.ProcessErrorAsync += HandleError;
            eventProcessorClient.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEventData;
            eventProcessorClient.StartProcessingAsync().Wait();
            checkpointTimer.Start();
        }

        public override async Task Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                checkpointTimer.Stop();
                await eventProcessorClient.StopProcessingAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                eventProcessorClient.ProcessEventAsync -= ProcessEventData;
                eventProcessorClient.ProcessErrorAsync -= HandleError;
            }
        }

        public override async Task Publish(string topic, JObject message)
        {
            using (EventDataBatch eventBatch = await eventHubProducerClient.CreateBatchAsync())
            {
                var @event = new Event(topic, message);
                string json = @event.ToString(Formatting.None);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                var eventData = new EventData(bytes);
                eventBatch.TryAdd(eventData);

                await eventHubProducerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
            }
        }

        private async Task ProcessEventData(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (eventArgs.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (++eventsSinceLastCheckpoint >= eventsToCheckpoint)
            {
                eventsSinceLastCheckpoint = 0;
                shouldUpdateCheckpoint = true;
            }

            if (shouldUpdateCheckpoint)
            {
                await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync();
                shouldUpdateCheckpoint = false;
            }

            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray());
            var @event = new Event(json);
            eventManager.TryRaise(@event);
        }

        private Task HandleError(ProcessErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (!eventArgs.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                errorHandler.Invoke($"[P:{eventArgs.PartitionId}][O:{eventArgs.Operation}] {eventArgs.Exception.Message}");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

I have found some info in [Service Bus Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) like:

> Number of concurrent receive requests on a queue, topic, or subscription entity (5000).
>
> Subsequent receive requests are rejected, and an exception is received
> by the calling code. This quota applies to the combined number
> of concurrent receive operations across all subscriptions on a topic.

But still can't figure how to deal with it.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your actual code please?

Comment: Can you share your send code?

Comment: Would you also please be so kind as to let us know what version of the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` package you're using?

Comment: I have added additional info to the question, guys.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're trying to do but it seems like you're performing a long running task (consuming eventhub data) in an asp.net web api, which might not be the best approach to tackle your problem.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, do you think that this is the cause of QuotaExceededException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the answer [EventHub Exception :Cannot allocate more handles to the current session or connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836828/eventhub-exception-cannot-allocate-more-handles-to-the-current-session-or-conne).

I did similar "fix" for Azure Event Hub library for **NET Core** but I have forgotten that I am also using Azure Event Hub library for **NET Framework**!

So I have instantiated `EventHubProducerClient` one time and reusing it now.
Seems working fine.

My bad. Was not attentive enough.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Where you have `eventProcessorClient.StartProcessingAsync().Wait();`,  I'd recommend calling `eventProcessorClient.StartProcessing()` instead of artificially blocking

Comment: You also do not appear to be calling `CloseAsync` or `DisposeAsync` on the producer client in the code that is shown, which is fine if you're using an application-wide instance - and that is likely the best approach.   However, if you're using the producer in a different scope, like per-request , you'll want to be sure to close it at the end of that scope to ensure that the connections and other resources can be cleaned up.   That is most likely the root cause of your issue.

Comment: @JesseSquire, but it is ok if `eventProcessorClient` is used from singleton, right?

Comment: It is;  all of the Event Hubs clients are safe to cache and use for the lifetime of an application.   When you're publishing/consuming regularly, that's the recommended pattern to use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, except creating only one instance of Client, use only one instance of sender.
I used method CreateSender each time when send a messsage, it also generates an exception